# Check for independence for exponential distributions

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two independent exponentially distributed random variables both with mean $\beta$ and suppose $W_1= X_1 + X_2 $ and $W_2= \frac{X_1}{X_2}$. Find the joint density function of $(W_1, W_2)$. Are $W_1$ and $W_2$ independent? Why?

$$
  f(x_1) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\beta}e^{-\frac{x_1}{\beta}},  & x>0 \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$

$$
  f(x_2) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\beta}e^{-\frac{x_2}{\beta}},  & x>0 \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$

$f(W_1) = F(x_1)+f(x_2)=\frac{1}{\beta}e^{-(\frac{x_1+x_2}{\beta})}$

$f(W_2)=\frac{f(x_1)}{f(x_2)}=e^{-(\frac{x_1-x_2}{\beta})}$

Is it good so far? How do I check for independence here?

Comment: what you have now is incorrect. you need transform $(X_1,X_2) \to (W_1,W_2)$ using the Jacobian method to find the joint density $f_{(W_1,W_2)}(w_1,w_2)$. Then, if this can be factored independently into $w_1$ and $w_2$ parts, you can conclude that $W_1$ and $W_2$ are independent

Comment: Could you please post a brief answer, I am not getting it.

Comment: Deleting a question after getting an answer is considered quite rude here. This is because you then also throw away the work the answerer put into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, their joint pdf is the product of their marginal pdfs.
$$
f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) = f_{X_1}(x_1) f_{X_2} (x_2) = \frac{1}{\beta^2} e^{ - \frac{1}{\beta}(x_1+x_2)} \cdot \mathbf{1}[ x_1, x_2 >0]
$$
Observe that $X_1 = \frac{W_1 W_2}{1+W_2}$ and $X_2 = \frac{W_1}{1+W_2}$. Then, we find the Jacobian:
$$
 \frac{d(x_1,x_2)}{d(w_1,w_2)}=
\left\vert \det \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{w_2}{1+w_2} & \frac{w_1}{(1+w_2)^2} \\
\frac{1}{1+w_2} & -\frac{w_1}{(1+w_2)^2}
\end{pmatrix}\right\vert  = \frac{w_1}{(1+w_2)^2}.
$$
Therefore, the joint pdf of $w_1$ and $w_2$ is:
\begin{align*}
f_{W_1,W_2}(w_1,w_2) &= \frac{1}{\beta^2} e^{ - \frac{1}{\beta} ( \frac{W_1}{1+W_2} + \frac{W_1W_2}{1+W_2})}  \cdot \frac{w_1}{(1+w_2)^2} \cdot \mathbf{1} \left[ \frac{W_1 W_2}{1+W_2} , \frac{W_1 }{1+W_2} > 0 \right]
 \\
& = \underbrace{\left[\frac{1}{\beta^2}  \left(w_1  e^{ - \frac{w_1}{\beta} } \right)  \cdot \mathbf{1}[w_1 >0] \right]}_{f_{W_1}(w_1)} \underbrace{ \left[ \frac{1}{(1+w_2)^2} \cdot \mathbf{1}[w_2>0] \right]}_{f_{W_2}(w_2)}. \end{align*}
So yes, they're independent.

Comment: +1. How did you get the marginal density for $W_1$ and $W_2$? I know that it can be obtained from integrating the joint density w.r.t $W_1$ and $W_2$ separately, just wondering if there is an easier way.

Comment: @darkgbm   Since the steps to find it are valid, then $f_{W_1,W_2}$ is a joint pdf, which shall integrate, over its joint support, to one.  As this may be factored into a constant and two monovariate functions, then independence is proven.  Integrating the *easiest* of these functions will determine how the constant is factored to normalise both into pdf.  $${\int_0^\infty (1+w)^{-2}\operatorname d w = \left[ -(1+w)^{-1} \right]_0^\infty = 1\\ \therefore\quad (1+w_2)^{-2}\mathbf 1[w_2>0]\text{ is the pdf for }W_2\\\text{The remainder must be the pdf for }W_1.}$$